# Will there be any problem publishing two android projects having two firebase accounts separately using the same Google Play Console account?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-console

Suppose, I have **two** android apps and both of them uses separate **firebase/firestore** account services.

Now, will there be any problem publishing both of the apps using the **same** Google Play Console account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short answer, you can publish many apps (belongs to different firebase accounts) in the same google play account

No constraints regarding the firebase account you linked the app to.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can have any (reasonable) number of apps accessing the same Firebase project, or different projects.  Google Play doesn't know or care about what Firebase projects an app is configured to use.  You just need to have a unique application ID for each app, and have each of them configured correctly in the Firebase project.

Comment: My answer is "no" to your question of "will there be any problem".  No, there will not be any problems as long as you've gone through the normal steps to set up the app.